# Faster NHibernate loading in multi-tenant environment

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, nhibernate, parallel-processing

I need to access hundreds of SQL servers with the same set of schemas using NHibernate. Each customer has several different databases for different functions. Each customer stores their own connection strings for their databases in a DatabaseEntity table as well as one global table which provides the initial connection. I need to use this for service and website functionality. Loading NHibernate to access these databases is taking an unacceptable amount of time.

Using this article https://patrickhuber.wordpress.com/2011/10/25/change-connectionstring-nhibernate/ I have discovered that using a single SessionFactory and changeable connection will lose second level cache as well as come up with other issues. Using the example in this article I have also tried caching the config and changing the connection, however the config.BuildSessionFactory() still takes a few seconds. Multiplied by 100s of customer DBs this is an issue.

An alternative is to use lazy-loading to only load the customer connection information when a request comes in. However this would mean several waits of several seconds for the customer the first time they log in which is not acceptable.

Another option is to load all database information concurrently at the start. I have tried using await/async to preload the database information and SessionFactory objects at startup with NHibernate functions such as ListAsync() and Task.WaitAll but this doesn't seem to work well with NHibernate (or I am missing something).

Below is some very simplified async code which started loading the information synchronously when var tasks is created. Please suggest alternatives or fixes to any of these options.

```
// Usage
IDictionary<long, IList<DatabaseEntity>> databaseList = await LoadDatabasesAsynchronously();

// Database entity contains connection information, schema and unique SessionFactory
// One database entity per customer should return a list of database entities per customer from the DatabaseEntity table
private static async Task<IDictionary<long, IList<DatabaseEntity>>> LoadDatabasesAsynchronously()
{
    // Each database entity has it's own SessionFactory
    IDictionary<long, IList<DatabaseEntity>> databaseDictionary = LoadDatabasesSynchronously(); // Key = Customer ID, Value = List of database entities in customer (one each to start with)
    var tasks = databaseDictionary.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => GetDatabases(v.Value.First())); // Load NHibernate query tasks
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.Select(kvp => kvp.Value).ToArray()); // Does not reach here
    return tasks.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value.GetAwaiter().GetResult());
}

private static async Task<IList<DatabaseEntity>> GetDatabases(DatabaseEntity database)
{
    using (TransactionRequired transaction = new TransactionRequired(database.Session))
    {
        return await database.Session.QueryOver<DatabaseEntity>().Where(x => x.Type == someType).ListAsync();
    }
}
```

Required is an IDictionary> populated concurrently using NHibernate based on a synchronously loaded IDictionary> which starts with one DatabaseEntity connection for each customer.

Comment: There is pending PR adding multi-tenancy feature https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/pull/2108. For now the best approach would be using custom build with changes applied from this PR.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize/deserialize nhibernate configuration. Deserialization can be faster than configuration build. Try this

```cs
private bool IsConfigurationFileValid
        {
            get
            {
                var assemblies = _configurationParameters.MappingAssemblies
                    .Where(mapAssembly => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(mapAssembly.Location))
                    .ToList();
                if (assemblies.Count == 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                var serializedConfigFileInfo = new FileInfo(SerializedConfigurationFilePath);
                return assemblies
                    .Select(mapAssembly => new FileInfo(mapAssembly.Location))
                    .Aggregate(true, (current, mapAssembly) => current & (mapAssembly.CreationTime <= serializedConfigFileInfo.CreationTime && mapAssembly.LastWriteTime <= serializedConfigFileInfo.LastWriteTime));
            }
        }

        private void SaveConfigurationToFile(NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration configuration)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var file = File.Open(SerializedConfigurationFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                    bf.Serialize(file, configuration);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _log.Fatal("Cant save serialized configuration", e);
            }
        }

        private NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration LoadConfigurationFromFile()
        {
            if (!IsConfigurationFileValid)
                return null;
            try
            {
                using (var file = File.Open(SerializedConfigurationFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                    var configurationFromFile = bf.Deserialize(file) as NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration;

                    if (configurationFromFile == null)
                        return null;

                    var currentConnectionString = configurationFromFile.GetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionString);

                    return currentConnectionString == _configurationParameters.ConnectionString
                        ? configurationFromFile
                        : null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _log.Info("LoadConfigurationFromFile failed", ex);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried this but we're using .NET Core and the BinaryFormatter doesn't seem to be able to serialize with this framework.